# How to encrypt a .plist before uploading to users Dropbox?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, encryption, plist

I've setup my app to work with Dropbox to implement a backup feature in my app. I could easily upload the plist files that contain the users data to dropbox but I want to encrypt the data before uploading it so that they cannot see the data it contains using a text editor. So how can I encrypt the data before uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only work I have done was encrypting user name and password and storing the encrypted value in the NSUserDefaults, and then decrypting it. I'm not sure if this class will help, but it's encryption methods are not too bad [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security).